# "Tightly connected to" or "Highly connected to"

Tags: expressions

What if I want to say topic 1 is tightly connected to topic 2? It's like to say quantum theory is "tightly connected" to applications like nuclear bombs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context you asked about, I'd suggest one of these alternative constructions:

> Closely connected with
>   Closely associated with
>   Closely bound up with
>   Highly relevant to
>   Essential for
>   Crucial for
>   Critical for

Answer (score 2):

"Tightly connected" means that each connection is very strong. "Highly connected" means that there are many connections. They are rather interchangeable in most contexts, as the expression is usually used somewhat metaphorically (as in, you're not thinking of individual connections).

Comment: Would you describe somebody with a lot of friends as "highly friended"?

Comment: @RoaringFish: Relevance? The OP is asking about "highly connected", not about "highly friended". Different phrases, different idioms, different connotations. To me, "highly connected" is a shorter way of saying "having a high degree of interconnection". It might be I am closer to mathematical jargon here, rather than general usage. For example, two good friends are tightly connected to each other, but a socialite is highly - but not tightly - connected in the society they move in.

Comment: Relevance... having a lot of something (such as connections) does not mean it is "highly [sth]". Having a lot of friends is not 'highly friended' and by identical reasoning having a lot of connections is not 'highly connected'. For the state of having a lot of connections, we use *connectivity*, which can be emphasised by high as it is specifically about the number - high or low- of connections.

Comment: @RoaringFish: No, no more than "[sth]cake" means "a person characterised as having body comparable to animal [sth] comes from". And yet, there's "beefcake". All that proves is that language shifts, substitutes, elides, implies, and bends in various other ways. "Highly connected" is a phrase that is in wide use, with a rather well defined semantics, despite it not being strictly decomposable in Fregean sense. Here, "highly" has no more to do with altitude than "French fries" with France, "pomme de terre" with earth or apples, "can of whup-ass" with behinds, or "hot dog" with canines.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Frege, who had a lot to say about Sinn & Bedeutung but nothing to say about adverbs. I am not sure whether you throwing that in to intimidate me or as a false appeal to authority... Nor is is semantics. It is just the innapropriatness of using an adverb of quantity where it should be quality. Something is either connected or not. There is no quantity involved. Only the quality of the connection changes. Would you say "those two sticks are highly tied together"?

Comment: @RoaringFish: Frege's [Principle of Compositionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality) purports to cover more than adverbs. And no, submitting further examples to illustrate your point does not work, because of reasons I already stated - this meaning works for *this phrase only*. [It is used](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22highly+connected%22), it is readily understandable, a native speaker who is not a prescriptivist picking a fight wouldn't think twice about it - thus, quite appropriate, from where I stand.

Comment: You cannot apply compositionality (which, btw, was not invented by Frege) to a two word construction. 'People say  it' is just another logical fallacy - an appeal to commons. Here is why it fails as an argument ->  https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#safe=off&hl=en&q=%22yesterday+I+go+shopping%22

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17943/discussion-between-amadan-and-roaring-fish).

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself if a connection can be tight. Then ask yourself if it can be high.

Clearly, a connection can be tight or loose, but high? Not so much. Perhaps you could say that when describing somebody socially connected to people in high places, but in the OP context of a close relationship *tightly* makes more sense.